# Parse Exception from a simple POST request

Tags: c++, docker, elasticsearch

I am using sockets in C++ to communicate with Elasticsearch. I can communicate with my ELK instance (it is running in a docker compose, the docker files are [here](https://github.com/BenjaFriend/docker-elk)).

Here is the request that I am sending:

```
POST /twitter/_doc/1? HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Host: 127.0.0.1:9200
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36
'{ "post_date" : "2017-11-16T14:12:12", "message" : "trying out Elasticsearch FROM CPPPPP" }'
Connection: close
```

And here is the response that I am getting from the server:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
content-length: 163

{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"parse_exception","reason":"request body is required"}],"type":"parse_exception","reason":"request body is required"},"status":400}
```

I can confirm that I am sending and receiving this data by counting the bytes being sent and received.

I am confused because when I put that request into the Kibana console, it runs fine.

Any ideas on what would be wrong with the request that I am sending?

Here is the C++ code where I create the request:

```
std::string post_http = "";
post_http += "POST /twitter/_doc/1? HTTP/1.1\n";
post_http += "Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8\n";
post_http += "Host: ";
post_http += aURL;
post_http += ":9200\n";
post_http += "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36\n";
post_http += "'{ \"post_date\" : \"2017-11-16T14:12:12\", ";
post_http += "\"message\" : \"trying out Elasticsearch FROM CPPPPP\" }'";
post_http += "\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n";
```

As far as I can tell it would be an issue with how I am creating the request in the code above.

Comment: "request body is required" = you are not properly sending data as message body.

Comment: Yes, do you have any idea how to do so? Is there a tag missing out something?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_message_body, body is whatever you put after an EMPTY LINE after the headers.
You have mixed body inside headers.

Comment: Added more info as answer, hope it solves your problem. If it does, please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, it appears you mixed body inside headers.
Thus you actually have no body in your HTTP message.

Please see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_message_body for a description of how an HTTP message is composed,  specifically pay attention to the need pof having an EMPTY line between headers and body.

In your case, a solution may be to change your post_http string to:

```
std::string post_http = "";
post_http += "POST /twitter/_doc/1? HTTP/1.1\r\n";
post_http += "Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
post_http += "Host: " + aURL + ":9200\r\n";
post_http += "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36\r\n";
post_http += "Connection: close\r\n"
post_http += "\r\n"; // EMPTY line between header and body.
post_http += "'{ \"post_date\" : \"2017-11-16T14:12:12\", ";
post_http += "\"message\" : \"trying out Elasticsearch FROM CPPPPP\" }'";
```

I've also changed line endings to be all consistent "\r\n", as specified in the linked article.

It may also help to define a string const to give a name to the line ending sequence,  e.g.:

```
const char* HTTP_LINE_END = "\r\n";
```

Comment: Just tried it and this doesn't seem to make a difference. I'm wondering if you need to wrap it quotes or something maybe?

Comment: The best you can do is:  
1. get a suitable tool to debug HTTP packets (WireShark or Fiddler comes to mind)  
2. use them to sniff a valid, accepted POST  
3. use it to sniff your invalid, not accepted POST  
4. check the differences between the 2  
that should give you enough comprehension of what is wrong in your request.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was coming from not having a `Content-Body` in the header, as well as how long the Socket was waiting for a response. It seems that contrary to the [WinSock documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winsock/sending-and-receiving-data-on-the-client), you should not call the `shutdown` method if you are waiting for a response from the server.

Here is what I ended up having for my finished method:

```
assert(strcmp(aMethod, "GET") || strcmp(aMethod, "POST") || strcmp(aMethod, "PUT"));

// TODO: Investigate if I actually need to reconnect the socket every time a request is made? 
ConnectSocket();

char Request[MAX_REQUEST_LEN];
strcpy_s(Request, MAX_REQUEST_LEN, aMethod);

strcat_s(Request, MAX_REQUEST_LEN, " ");
strcat_s(Request, MAX_REQUEST_LEN, aIndexParam);
strcat_s(Request, MAX_REQUEST_LEN, RequestHeader);

strcat_s(Request, MAX_REQUEST_LEN, "Content-Length: ");
strcat_s(Request, MAX_REQUEST_LEN, std::to_string(strlen(aMsg)).c_str());
strcat_s(Request, MAX_REQUEST_LEN, "\r\n");

strcat_s(Request, MAX_REQUEST_LEN, ConnectionClose);
strcat_s(Request, MAX_REQUEST_LEN, aMsg);
strcat_s(Request, MAX_REQUEST_LEN, "\r\n");
```

As you can see, I moved to just using `char *` instead of `std::String`, which gave me about a 30% performance boost. Also, There is now a `Content-Length` tag in the header.

This is what my final headers look like:

```
POST /twitter/_doc/ HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Content-Encoding: identity
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36
Host:  HTTP/1.1
127.0.0.1:9200
Content-Length: 112
Connection: close

{ "user" : "kimchy", "post_date" : "2018-09-16T14:12:12", "message" : "trying out Elasticsearch FROM c++ BOII" }
```